# Can't spy on CheckListBox with AutoIt

Tags: python, delphi, robotframework, autoit, pywinauto

I can't spy on CheckListBox object (I think Delphi) in a window frame with AutoIt. It can't see anything in the area. I need to get the list of items from the area and possibly select one the items.

I am using python and robotframework.

I also tried using ControlListView:

```
self.get_autoit().ControlListView("Setup - XXXXX", "Select the XXXX", "[CLASS:TNewCheckListBox; INSTANCE:1]", "GetText")
```

But it throws:

```
com_error: (-2147352561, 'Parameter not optional.', None, None)
```

The error seems to be an issue with pywinauto.

Anyway I can not get the list of items from this annoying object.

The result from autoit spy is in screenshot:

[image: result from autoit spy]

Can anyone please suggest a good way to access the list of items in this unidentified area?

I can see the inside items from inspect.exe:

[image: from inspect.exe]

Comment: This doesn't look like a a TCheckListBox, it looks like a TRadioGroup

Comment: [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) or [pyautoit](https://github.com/jacexh/pyautoit)? There are 2 different libraries. It seems you use pyautoit, not pywinauto.

Comment: I am using pywinauto. autoitlibrary in robot framework uses pywinauto.

Comment: This comes as TCheckListBox in spy.

Comment: This is *not* a `TCheckListBox`. A `TCheckListBox` is (as the name indicates) a *listbox* that has *checkboxes* next to each item, and you can check off multiple items to select them. What your image shows are two *radiobuttons*, which are *not* checkboxes. That's a radio group or a pair of radio buttons. Whatever *Spy* you're using has misidentified the control, which we can't change. And how is an issue with AutoIt and Python a Delphi question?

Comment: @KumarGaurav I see AutoIt style, not pywinauto's. You really mix these different libraries. pyautoit is a Python binding for AutoIt, but pywinauto is pure Python library not connected with AutoIt community. Using pywinauto you should write something like `app.window(title_re='Setup - .*').child_window(class_name='TNewCheckListBox', found_index=0).window_text()`.

Comment: Did you try `Inspect.exe` to spy these controls? It can be found in Windows SDK (some of `Program Files` folders).

Comment: @Vasily: I just tried win SDK inspect. and I could spy the controls. The screenshot is attached with question. Sorry, yes you are right, I am using autoit. I don't know where It got confused. I have pywinauto installed so I tried following: app = Application().connect(title_re = self.installerTitle)     text = app.window(title_re = self.installerTitle).child_window(class_name='TNewCheckListBox', found_index=0).window_text() but it gives empty string. I am new to pywinauto and am going through the documentation however if you can help here using inspect.exe image, it would be really great. :)

Comment: TNewCheckListBox is not actually (directly) a Delphi control, and it's only loosely based on a Windows list box. It's a custom component that is part of InnoSetup (the installation builder), and you can find the documentation in the [Inno Setup documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm). As internally it uses something other than the standard WinAPI classes for storage, it's unlikely you're going to be able to access the items directly. It's probably better to contact the setup app author and ask them to add command line options for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: To clarify, when I say *not actually (directly)*, I mean that Inno Setup itself is written in Delphi, but that control is not part of the standard Delphi VCL; it's a custom control that is available to those using Inno Setup's Pascal script to customize the installation to meet their specific needs. There's a link to the source for Inno Setup itself on the web site I linked, which you can retrieve from GitHub and examine directly to see if it's helpful. The items are not stored in the window's text, but as part of the radio button class. (I accidentally found TNewCheckListBox today.)

Comment: If `Inspect.exe` can see the controls, you'd better use `Application(backend="uia").start(...)` as an entry point. Read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for difference between Win32 API and UI Automation and how it's handled.

Comment: @Vasily using backend="uia" I can get the text however I am struggling to iterate over the child_windows.. is there a way to get the count of child windows of a specific window? works:  `app.window(title_re=self.installerTitle, found_index=0).child_window(class_name='TNewCheckListBox', found_index=0).child_window(found_index=0).window_text()` also works: `app.window(title_re=self.installerTitle, found_index=0).child_window(class_name='TNewCheckListBox', found_index=0).child_window(found_index=1).window_text()` but I would like to iterate to get all values. checking docs but didn't get so far.

Comment: `.print_control_identifiers()` dumps all the descendants. Or you can call `.children()` for immediate children list (`.descendants()` is the same but for the whole subtree of controls).

Comment: Thanks @Vasily, I could get a list of controls using children(). In Debug mode, I get ButtonWrapper as the children: `<pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.ButtonWrapper object at 0x034C4930>` However I can't use methods to click on the button. Only method that works is: select() which highlights (blue) the radio button label (doesn't select the radio button). Also in debug mode, I see the control type of element as RadioButton.

Comment: Thanks @Vasily, I could get a list of controls using children(). In Debug mode, I get ButtonWrapper as the children: `<pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.ButtonWrapper object at 0x034C4930>` However I can't use methods to click on the button. click() and toggle() gives `NoPatternInterfaceError`. Only method that works is: select() which highlights (blue) the radio button label (doesn't select the radio button). Also in debug mode, I see the control type of element as RadioButton. Any idea how to select the radio button. Thanks a lot for your help, it has been very very useful.

Comment: `.invoke()` or `.click_input()` don't help?

Comment: @vasily click_input() did work! Thanks a lot! You can summarise the answer if you want in the answer section so that I can mark that as an answer. Just wondering, are you one of the contributors in pywinauto?

Comment: Yes, I revived the project as an open source about 2 years ago. There are 2 experienced contributors (me & airelil) & 3 students now working on the project. Sorry for the delay, just went back from the holidays trip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the detailed answer from Vasily in the comments. However to summarize:

In the original question, I was trying to get the list of items from CheckListBox using pyautoit however as it was not working. So, as suggested by Vasily, I used pywinauto (another automation tool) in UIA mode and following worked for me:

```
self.Wizard = Application(backend="uia").connect(title = self.installerTitle) #connect the application
self.Wizard.InstallerDialog.TreeView.wait('visible', timeout=150) #wait for tree view to load
        items = self.Wizard.InstallerDialog.TreeView.children() #get the children of tree view
        for item in items:  #iterate through items, radio button in this case
            if item.window_text() == "item_name_to_select":
                item.click_input() #click radio button if the text is what we are looking for
                return
        print "no item found with name: item_name_to_select"
```

The most helpful trick was to use `print_control_identifiers()` method in pywinauto to get the identifiers of the control. Also the `inspect.exe` in `uia` mode helped in identifying the objects.

Comment: If you found the solution, and want to share it with us, then post the entire solution as answer. It's difficult to read multiple comments and guess which combination of answers is the solution.